# Raising an Exception in a function

Tags: python, exception

Let say we have a program like this:

```
def age(age):
    if age <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid age")
    return age


try:
    age(-1)
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
```

The output of this program is `"Invalid age"`. I don't understand the reason why we get this output. In my age function,  does the statement, `raise ValueError("Invalid age")` assign `"Invalid age"` to the `ValueError`?
So whenever this exception is raised, "Invalid age" gets printed?
And what does this, (`except ValueError as error` statement) actually do?

Comment: `error` is the `ValueError` object. `print(error)` calls the `__repr__` method on that object - which, for the `ValueError` class, returns the `message` - which happens to be `Invalid age`

Comment: Which parts of this *do* you understand? Are you familiar with the basics of Python? Do you know what ``except:`` or ``except ValueError:`` does? Do you know what ``print(-1)`` would do?